# What is grass-fertilizer-fluid sprayed on soil?

Tags: grass, seeds

In Southern Texas, I have seen a cyan-colored, viscous, sticky fluid sprayed from a huge tank track on freshly compacted ground. I later realized that this fluid most probably contained grass seeds and fertilizer as within days the Texas-typical broad-leaved gras started to germinate.

What exactly is that mixture? Is really glue inside? Is that available to hobby gardners in Europe?

Comment: Papier-mâché is some of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've described is [hydroseeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroseeding), invented in the US in the 1940s. It's a slurry of grass seed, water, and other ingredients that help "stick" the seed to the soil and in most cases, cover it with a thin mulch. As these sites show, it's certainly available in the [UK](http://hydroflex-eu.com/) and [EU](https://www.environmental-expert.com/companies/keyword-hydroseeding-13431/location-europe).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not know the official term before. As far as I can tell, hydroseeding is rather a large-scale approach, and not necessarily available for private persons, at least not in Germany. Here, the market is dominated by [sod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod).

Comment: Hydroseeding seems to be the standard for highway construction sites. Any color dye an be used.

Comment: Its certainly used a lot in the usa. My neighbor hydroseeded and it is cool I used to laugh thinking it would never grow. He has the best grass in the neighborhood.